# Multidimensional array in Javascript, with 650 entries

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensionnal array to fill with 450 entries, each entries having 3 IDs.

Here's a snapshot of what I'm trying to achieve :

1. Country1

   1. Site1

      1. Page1  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      2. Page2  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      3. Page3  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
   2. Site2

      1. Page1  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      2. Page2  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      3. Page3  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
   3. Site3

      1. Page1  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      2. Page2  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
      3. Page3  >> ID1, ID2, ID3
2. Country2
     1.etc.

Since there are many entries, I need to find a way to create it and populate it using the most productive way possible, but all I've found so far is this :

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = "country1";
myArray["country1"] = new Array("site1","site2","site3");
myArray["country1"]["site1"] = new Array("page1", "page2", "page3");
myArray["country1"]["site1"]["page1"] = new Array("782618","548836","2963259");
myArray["country1"]["site1"]["page2"]= new Array("782619","548837","2963260");
```

Would you know any other way that wouldn't need me to inject each entry using 4 lines of codes ?

Thanks a lot for your time guys !

Comment: I think you are getting `array` and `object` mixed up here...

Comment: You can use a loop and a counter.

Comment: all data may be variable? (site with 3/12/200 pages or 3 fixed ecc...)

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: Nope, all data is hardcoded and has to be entered manually. Then, on a web page, based on the value of country, site and page, I'll send a specific event. Some sites have more than 25 page and I have 7/8 sites with 6/7 countries available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hardcoded values, obviously simplest way is:

```
    var myArray = [{
    "country1": {
        "site1": {
            "page1": ["782618","548836","2963259"]
        }
    },
    "country2": {
        "site2": {
            "page2": ["782619","548837","2963260"]
        }
    }
}]
```